# How to use with() on model instance

Tags: eloquent

I have model relationship as such Manager > Employee > Orders > Orderlines
I want to get all the Orderlines under a Manager, so I go:

```
$manager = Manager::find(1);
$surprise = $manager->with('employees.orders.orderlines')->get();
```

I expect `$surprise` to have only data from 1 manager, but it is fetching all data from all managers. What is the correct usage such that I only get orderlines from the Manager model instance?